# How to hide a layout on pressing BackButton in Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have an Activity having multiple fragments of tabs, on pressing "Running total " button present at the bottom, the UI of that particular tab hides and another layout which displays a table,is shown. I want to display the main UI of the tab and hide that table layout on pressing device's back button. I can't use BackStack as I'm using horizonal naviagtion(tabs). How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply override the `onBackPressed()` in your activity and write the logic there to handle what you want to do.

If you going to manipulate fragment during `onBackPressed`, it could be done by overriding `onBackPressed` in the `Activity` itself. But this would mess up the Fragment-Activity communication. It's better to have `onBackPressed` in the Fragment also.

A simple google search will give you multiple links on how to have `onBackPressed` in `Fragment`.
Follow the below link for how to implement this: http://vinsol.com/blog/2014/10/01/handling-back-button-press-inside-fragments/

Comment: Yes it can't be done. You could do it via implementing an interface. But I am asking you to override it in the `Activity` only.

Comment: My activity has override onBackpressed() but it is not interacting with the fragment..How can I do it by implementing interface?

Comment: Updated my above. Use that.